# Installed ros-kinetic-turtlebot-gazebo but something weird

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I am getting wrapped around the axle with respect to paths or apt-get so I thought I would ask this...

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot-gazebo
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

and still when I do

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

I get an error because turtlebot_gazebo doesn't exist. roscd turtlebot_gazebo similarly doesn't work. Because I have turtlebot3 packages installed, I am able to see turtlebot3_gazebo but I believe that has nothing to do with anything. Can someone see where I am going wrong?

#### Updates (thanks @gvdhoorn)

I  did the following to try and troubleshoot:

```
sudo apt-get remove turtlebot_gazebo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install turtlebot_gazebo
```

And thnings got better, but still weird. After that:

```
 dpkg -l | grep turtlebot
ii  ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup                2.4.2-0xenial-20180803-215945-0800                    amd64        turtlebot_bringup provides roslaunch scripts for starting the TurtleBot base functionality.
ii  ros-kinetic-turtlebot-capabilities           2.4.2-0xenial-20180516-155341-0800                    amd64        Capabilities for the TurtleBot
ii  ros-kinetic-turtlebot-description            2.4.2-0xenial-20180803-190853-0800                    amd64        turtlebot_description provides a complete 3D model of the TurtleBot for simulation and visualization.
ii  ros-kinetic-turtlebot-gazebo                 2.2.3-0xenial-20180804-004347-0800                    amd64        Gazebo launchers and worlds for TurtleBot simulation
ii  ros-kinetic-turtlebot-navigation             2.3.7-0xenial-20180804-001200-0800                    amd64        turtlebot_navigation


~/catkin_ws/src/rosbook$ rospack profile
Full tree crawl took 0.038709 seconds.
Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may
want to delete these directories.
To get just of list of directories without manifests,
re-run the profile with --zombie-only
-------------------------------------------------------------
0.033712   /opt/ros/kinetic/share
0.003433   /home/pitosalas/catkin_ws/src
0.001256   /home/pitosalas/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3
0.000575   /home/pitosalas/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_simulations
0.000362 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev
0.000070 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev/haarcascades
0.000069 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/man
0.000052 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/doc
0.000039 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev/lbpcascades
0.000017 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/man/man1
0.000011 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/doc/liborocos-kdl
pitosalas@RpsUbuntu:~/catkin_ws/src/rosbook$ rospack find turtlebot
```

Now, gazebo crashes:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
... logging to /home/pitosalas/.ros/log/b0dd6d1a-a3a2-11e8-86c8-002500efe1ca/roslaunch-RpsUbuntu-4793.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://RpsUbuntu:46543/

SUMMARY


PARAMETERS
 * /bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud_radius: 0.24
 * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file: /opt/ros/kinetic/...
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/output_frame_id: /camera_depth_frame
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/range_min: 0.45
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/scan_height: 10
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 30.0
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.13
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    bumper2pointcloud (nodelet/nodelet)
    cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
    depthimage_to_laserscan (nodelet/nodelet)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    laserscan_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    spawn_turtlebot_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4809]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to b0dd6d1a-a3a2-11e8-86c8-002500efe1ca
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4822]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [4825]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [4830]
process[spawn_turtlebot_model-4]: started with pid [4836]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5]: started with pid [4850]
process[cmd_vel_mux-6]: started with pid [4858]
process[bumper2pointcloud-7]: started with pid [4859]
process[robot_state_publisher-8]: started with pid [4860]
process[laserscan_nodelet_manager-9]: started with pid [4869]
process[depthimage_to_laserscan-10]: started with pid [4876]
[ INFO] [1534677982.040233550]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1534677982.041887402]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1534677982.079742821]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1534677982.083048662]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1534677983.176051364, 0.030000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[ INFO] [1534677983.941702262, 0.030000000]: Camera Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
[ INFO] [1534677983.949456848, 0.030000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[ INFO] [1534677984.183192948, 0.030000000]: Starting plugin Kobuki(ns = //)
[ WARN] [1534677984.183265999, 0.030000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): missing <rosDebugLevel> default is na
[ INFO] [1534677984.187131699, 0.030000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): <tf_prefix> = 
[ INFO] [1534677984.187380418, 0.030000000]: Will publish tf. [mobile_base]
[ INFO] [1534677984.190451132, 0.030000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise joint_states[joint_states]!
[ INFO] [1534677984.191653523, 0.030000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise Odometry[odom]!
[ INFO] [1534677984.195429549, 0.030000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[ INFO] [1534677984.198317835, 0.030000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Try to subscribe to mobile_base/commands/motor_power!
[ INFO] [1534677984.204892752, 0.030000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Try to subscribe to mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry!
[ INFO] [1534677984.211005128, 0.030000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Try to subscribe to mobile_base/commands/velocity!
[ INFO] [1534677984.212095398, 0.030000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise Cliff[mobile_base/events/cliff]!
[ INFO] [1534677984.213190076, 0.030000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise Bumper[mobile_base/events/bumper]!
[ INFO] [1534677984.214262325, 0.030000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise IMU[mobile_base/sensors/imu_data]!
[ INFO] [1534677984.214316523, 0.030000000]: GazeboRosKobuki plugin ready to go! [mobile_base]
[ INFO] [1534677984.240456409, 0.060000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[spawn_turtlebot_model-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/pitosalas/.ros/log/b0dd6d1a-a3a2-11e8-86c8-002500efe1ca/spawn_turtlebot_model-4*.log
[ INFO] [1534677984.526572116, 0.340000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[58752]
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 4830, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/pitosalas/.ros/log/b0dd6d1a-a3a2-11e8-86c8-002500efe1ca/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/pitosalas/.ros/log/b0dd6d1a-a3a2-11e8-86c8-002500efe1ca/gazebo_gui-3*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300912/installed-ros-kinetic-turtlebot-gazebo-but-something-weird/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-08-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-19**:\

> ```
> sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get
> ```

```
upgrade sudo apt-get install
```

this is a bit jumbled up, I'm guessing this needs to be three separate lines?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-19**:
As always when checking why pkgs can't be found / appear not to be installed:

- pay attention to the output of `apt-get`: did it indicate successful installation?
- what is the output of `dpkg -l | grep turtlebot`?
- run `rospack profile`, then `rospack find turtlebot_gazebo`: does that work?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-19**:\

> Can someone see where I am going wrong?

I'm also assuming that you're `source`ing your base ROS installation / workspace before trying to run `roslaunch`.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-19**:
Yes, and see updates above.Whoops. Seem to have exceeded allowed lengrh.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-19**:
Theories: 1) turtlebot_* packages are actually not compatible with Kinetic.2) I also have turtlebot3 packages installed and they are interfering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looked like excellent advice from @gvdhorn:

"As always when checking why pkgs can't be found / appear not to be installed:"

- pay attention to the output of apt-get: did it indicate successful installation?
- what is the output of dpkg -l | grep turtlebot?
- run rospack profile, then rospack find turtlebot_gazebo: does that work?

In the end these techniques didn't get to the bottom of it, but something must have been wrong with my installation or environment and sadly I had to uninstall and reinstall ROS. I wonder whether this is not an unusual situation because I do try to be quite careful when installing things.

---

Originally posted by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) with karma: 628 on 2018-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0